# Can I run two processes in the main thread simultaneously

Tags: android, multithreading, android-alertdialog

I have a problem with the mainthread.
What I am trying to do is showing an alertdilog with the message "printing" while the printing task is running (printing and displaying the alertdialog are Simultaneous).
The problem is that the alertdialog is not showing until the printing is done.
I should mentiong that both alertdialog and the printing task need to be running in the main thread (getActivity.runonuithread.....).

My question is, can I run two different tasks in the main thread Simultaneously.

I tried running the printing task in a background thread but it is not working. The printing takes a long time and stops throught out the process.

```
private void SWIPE1() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                  //some code
                    ImpresssionDialog()
                    ImpressionTicket();

}}).start();



private void ImpresssionDialog() {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            optionDialogimp = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            String alert1 = "Impression .....";
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            optionDialogimp.setTitle(alert1);
            optionDialogimp.show();
            optionDialogimp.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        }
    });
}





private void ImpressionTicket() {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         //printing process ....
   }});
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to run printing on the main thread? It seems like a heavy task that might block the ui thread and the app might crash eventually. As far as I remember the ui thread runs sequentially meaning that it can do only one task at a time that it receives from a message queue using a looper.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show alert dialog, while printing, I suggest you should use AsyncTask. It has a few methods you can override:

`onPreExecute()` − (**Optional method**) Before doing background operation we should show something on screen like progressbar or any animation to user. we can directly comminicate background operation using on doInBackground() but for the best practice, we should call all asyncTask methods. Here you can start showing your alert dialog.

`doInBackground(Params)` − (**Mandatory method**) In this method we have to do background operation on background thread. Operations in this method should not touch on any mainthread activities or fragments. Do the actual printing work here.

`onPostExecute(Result)` − (**Optional method**) In this method we can update ui of background operation result. Dismiss your alert dialog.

`onProgressUpdate(Progress…)` − (**Optional method**) While doing background operation, if you want to update some information on UI, we can use this method.